# Eclipse: Appengine SDK JARs on WEBinf/lib

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, jar, eclipse-plugin

Everytime I update the Appengine SDK, I have to manually copy-paste some JAR files from the Eclipse/plugin to the WEB-INF/lib folder. The reason is that I get "missing file" errors on Eclipse until I do that.

Why isn't Eclipse looking for the JARs at the plugin folder? Is there a way to configure it at the build-path? Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**.Jar files copying**

Normally the Google plugin for Eclipse will copy the required .jar files to your WEB-INF/lib folder automatically.

If as you say it is not doing it then I'd check the settings at:

- Project properties > Google > App Engine
- Project properties > Google > Web Application

If they seem correct then you might disable "Use Google App Engine" on the project and re-enable it to trigger it to copy .jar files and potentially resolve your issue.

**Build Path**

You shouldn't need to play with this for GAE jars, when the project is configured properly as above a build path container for GAE should be added automatically.

Manually setting the build path yourself isn't advised because while it may show in eclipse that all is fine, when you launch your project in the web container (Jetty) then you'll get potentially get errors as Jetty won't be aware of your Eclipse build path and sets it's own.

Comment: This worked for me. It appears the problem can occur when importing a Google App project. I disabled 'Use Google App Engine' and then Eclipse got rid of the library in the Build Path and then imported all the Jars individually for some reason (probably auto-imported jar classes it depended on). So I manually selected those and removed them. Then renabled 'Use Google App Engine' and it worked.

Comment: A lot of screwed up happen when you update with debug version still running on the background.